# Describing the attribution of a machine's characteristics to humans

Tags: synonyms

Is there a word, an opposite of anthropomorphism, that describes the attribution of a machine's characteristics to humans (e.g., speaking of humans as though they were computers)?   Or, when we describe computers in terms of human qualities, we anthropomorphize.  What do we do when we conceptualize ourselves in terms of computers?

Comment: Is *dehumanize* too general?

Comment: We could coin *mechanomorphism*. Computation is a formal, mechanical process (lambda calculus, Turing machine, combinatory logic). Of course, not every mechanical system is a universal computing machine. Still, it emphasizes adoption of a mechanical model for things that might not fit or deserve it, just as *anthropomorphism* imposes a human model on things that might not fit.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can express the concept of attributing the characteristics of a machine to a human being as:

Human [robotization](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/robotization) :

> - the process of turning a human being into a robot

Source: www.merriam-webster.com